# Mysql select entry from parent table with spacific entries in child table manay to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, select, many-to-many

I have a Product table that has a many to many relation with product properties table. Now I want to select a product that has three product properties.

Here is my schema

[image]

And here is my data

1. Product

[image: Product table id, name and group_id]

2. Property

[image: Product property table id, name and type]

3. product_property

[image: product to property table]

I want to get product id that has property 1,4 and 7 e.g. product 1. 
Or I wan to search product that has property 2, 5 and 7

I have tried inner join and groups but can't find a solution.

```
select * from product as p join product_property as pp on p.id = pp.product_id join property as pt on pp.property_id = pt.id
```

I have created a sample at sqlfiddle here for testing. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aee4f

**Update**
I managed to find solution using Exists but I want some elegant solution

```
select * from product as p where exists (select * from product_property pp where pp.property_id=1 and p.id=pp.product_id) and exists (select * from product_property pp where pp.property_id=4 and p.id=pp.product_id ) and exists (select * from product_property pp where pp.property_id=7 and p.id=pp.product_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For extactly 3 properties:

```
select product_id
from product_property
group by product_id
having count(property_id) = 3
```

for at least 3 properties:

```
select product_id
from product_property
group by product_id
having count(property_id) >= 3
```

If you have duplicated in your product_property table then you need to use `count(distinct property_id)`.

**Update:** For your updated query you can use the following. If I summarize your question in my words *you need all those product ids which are having all three property_ids 1, 4 and 7*.

```
select p.* from product p
join product_property pp on p.id=pp.product_id
where pp.property_id in (1, 4, 7)
group by p.id
having count(pp.product_id) = 3;
```

Comment: I don't want a count but I want to filter on property ids 1,4 and 7.

Comment: Updated the new code. Misunderstood the question earlier.

Comment: Still not working Your query result is `1| product 1 | 1 ` and `4| product 4 | 2 `  but property 1,4, and 7 are only lined with `1 | product 1 | 1`

Comment: Sorry pal I made a typo. Check now.